# Is there any android app to capture screen when anything gets change on screen?

Tags: android, android-activity, screen, screenshot

We are running live test on our android application to detect any changes on the screen. Is there any app/way to capture the screenshot if anything gets change on the mobile screen?

Regards
Anujais

Comment: Do you have a way of detecting the changes?  If you do, then this post should solve your problems:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android

Comment: Thanks but i already checked it out there. cudn't find

Comment: @GKnight  I don't want to make it part of my program, We have only way to capture it by screen. actually there are some randomly occurring bugs  from unknown source which we need to figure it out.